# Regular Expression in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, asp.net-mvc

I want a ng-pattern expression to validate textbox which 'Should not accept **Only** Numeric or Special character. It should have at least one alphabet with numeric and special character' in angular js.
Example: 
1) a1234$ It is acceptable
2) 123%% It is not acceptable
3) abc It is acceptable
4) 56456a It is acceptable
5)123$%^abc It is acceptable

Above scenario should be validate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the hyphen at the end of your character class. When it is the last character it is assumed as a literal hyphen. For example: /^[a-zA-Z-]*$/

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z-]*$/" ng-model="" name="">
</form>
```

Comment: okey,before edited your question it was different senerio for Now I have different answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these checks using positive look ahead assertions.
use that regex in ng-pattern

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].)$
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/UAwoaPM0Ji

```
^                         Start anchor
(?=.*[A-Z].)              Ensure string has one uppercase letters.
(?=.*[!@#$&*])            Ensure string has one special case letter.
(?=.*[0-9].)              Ensure string has one digits.
(?=.*[a-z].)              Ensure string has one lowercase letters.
$                         End anchor.


You Can use this code as per your requirement.
```